# Highcharts - Dynamically change chart type with on radio buttons click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, drilldown

I am trying to change my working `highcharts` into different type of chart using `4 radio buttons`: `column`, `bar`, `pie`, `line`.

Here is my working chart:

```
$(function () {    


// Create the chart

var options = {
    chart: {
       events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
                if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                    var chart = this,

                        drilldowns = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>,
                        series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

                    // Show the loading label
                    chart.showLoading('Loading ...');

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                    }, 1000); 
                }

            }
        },
        plotBorderWidth: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Chart Title',
    },
    //
    subtitle: {
            text: 'Subtitle'
    },
    //
    xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
    },
    //
    yAxis: {

            title: {
                margin: 10,
                text: 'No. of user'
            },      
    },
    //
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    //
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        pie: {
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            size: '100%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
            }
        }
    },
    //
     series: [{
        name: 'Case',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data:data_array,
    }],
    //
    drilldown: {
        series: []
    }
};

// Column chart
options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
options.chart.type = 'column';
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

As you can see a `drilldown` column type will be the default type of the chart and i want to add radio button where user can choose type of chart. Then I want to disable "LINE" radio button when the chart is in main series state and enable it when in drilldown series state.

Here are my radio buttons:

```
  <input type="radio" name="mychart" class="mychart" id= "column" value="column" onclick= "chartfunc()">Column
<input type="radio" name="mychart" class="mychart" id= "bar" value="bar" onclick= "chartfunc()">Bar
<input type="radio" name="mychart" class="mychart" id= "pie" value="pie" onclick= "chartfunc()">Pie
<input type="radio" name="mychart" class="mychart" id= "line" value="line" onclick= "chartfunc()">Line
```

the i add this script:

```
function chartfunc()
{
var column = document.getElementById('column');
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
var pie = document.getElementById('pie');
var line = document.getElementById('line');

if(column.checked)
    {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'column';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
else if(bar.checked)
    {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'bar';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
else if(pie.checked)
    {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'pie';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
else
    {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'line';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

}
```

Is it possible with this script?

P.S.
As you can see also the default title of chart is 'Chart Title', I want also to dynamically change it using textbox.. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/sSLnn/)**

code:

```
$(function () {    


// Create the chart

var options = {
    chart: {
       events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
                if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                    var chart = this;



                    // Show the loading label
                    chart.showLoading('Loading ...');

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                    }, 1000); 
                }

            }
        },
        plotBorderWidth: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Chart Title',
    },
    //
    subtitle: {
            text: 'Subtitle'
    },
    //
    xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
    },
    //
    yAxis: {

            title: {
                margin: 10,
                text: 'No. of user'
            },      
    },
    //
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    //
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        pie: {
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            size: '100%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
            }
        }
    },
    //
     series: [{
        name: 'Case',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    }],
    //
    drilldown: {
        series: []
    }
};

// Column chart
options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
options.chart.type = 'column';
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

chartfunc = function()
{
var column = document.getElementById('column');
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
var pie = document.getElementById('pie');
var line = document.getElementById('line');


if(column.checked)
    {

        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'column';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
else if(bar.checked)
    {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'bar';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
else if(pie.checked)
    {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'pie';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
else
    {
        options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        options.chart.type = 'line';
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

}

$('#change_chart_title').click(function(){
var new_title = $('#chart_title').val();
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.setTitle({ text: new_title });

alert('Chart title changed to '+new_title+' !');

});
    });
```

Comment: nice.. how i'm gonna disable "LINE" radio button if it is in main series state and enable it in when in drilldown series state?

Comment: and is it possible if chart wont reload if i change the text of chart title.. Sorry for too many questions.. =) Thanks

Comment: I have updated my code. The chart will not reload when title will be changed. I'm not sure about how to disable the radio button when drilldown. Please consider accepting the answer ! :)

Comment: oh, i'm sorry.. http://jsfiddle.net/lorwynz_11/sSLnn/3/   i've updated the jsfiddle you gave me.. when in drilldown series state when i change chart type it will back to main series state.