# Buttons to switch between Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

OK, 2nd ever post, now (I hope) in the right place, but apols if I haven't quite got the hang of things here.

I have a Highmap (link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drsimevans/jp4edbxc/)) and I would like to add buttons so as to switch between datasets. Here's the current code, based on one of the stock Highmaps demos:

```
        $(function () {
        Highcharts.data({

            googleSpreadsheetKey: '1AAJXahB_I6twO5j4lUsjKyCwChK7fDkK8JsGz1LE7k4',

            // custom handler when the spreadsheet is parsed
            parsed: function (columns) {

                // Read the columns into the data array
                var data = [];
                $.each(columns[0], function (i, code) {
                    data.push({
                        code: code.toUpperCase(),
                        value: parseFloat(columns[2][i]),
                        name: columns[1][i]
                    });
                });


            // Initiate the chart
            $('#container1').highcharts('Map', {
                chart: {
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                style: {
                    fontFamily: "PT Sans"
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Renewable electricity shares in 2015',
                    align: 'left'
                },

                mapNavigation: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                enabled: false
                },

                legend: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Share of total',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    },
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    floating: true,
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    y: 20,
                    valueDecimals: 0,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)',
                    symbolRadius: 0,
                    symbolHeight: 14
                },

                colorAxis: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 100,
                    type: 'linear',
                gridLineWidth: 0.5,
                gridLineColor: 'white',
                minorTickInterval: 0.1,
                minorGridLineColor: 'white',
                tickLength: 0,
                    minColor: 'rgba(11,69,114,0.05)',
                    maxColor: 'rgba(11,69,114,1)',
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgba(11,69,114,0.05)'],
                        [0.5, 'rgba(11,69,114,0.7)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(11,69,114,1)']
                    ]
                },



                series: [{
                    data: data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-robinson-highres'],
                    joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                    animation: true,
                    name: 'Renewable share',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#EFC530'
                        }
                    },

                    tooltip: {
//                        valuePrefix: '\u20AC',
                        valueSuffix: ' %',
                        valueDecimals: 0
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#container').html('<div class="loading">' +
                '<i class="icon-frown icon-large"></i> ' +
                'Error loading data from Google Spreadsheets' +
                '</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

I saw a really elegant-looking way to implement buttons in this answer by Mike Zavarello:

[add custom drop down menu in highcharts/highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356956/add-custom-drop-down-menu-in-highcharts-highstock/37370336#37370336)

I would like to reproduce something similar. I'm reasonably OK with the Highcharts/Highmaps side of things but am new to the idea of adding code for buttons or dropdowns, so other suggested solutions with links to Fiddles I've seen are somewhat beyond my understanding. Couple of examples:

[Highcharts change chart type with radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693506/highcharts-change-chart-type-with-radio-buttons)

or

[Switching between many Highcharts using buttons or link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891763/switching-between-many-highcharts-using-buttons-or-link-text)

I guess I will need to have the data in separate google spreadsheets (at the moment at least, I am calling the data from google sheets, though I suspect JSON might be better, even though I don't really understand what a JSON is). I might also need to adjust settings for the legend etc. But those are details. Would it be easier to just replace the Highmap with another, based on the button press?

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Comment: If you are not changing the underlying map but just the data then doing a simple update of the chart's series would be easiest.

Comment: When you don't have a lot of data, you can store two datasets in one google spreadsheet and then store it as arrays in Highcharts. Then on update, you can only switch saved without unnecesary requests. https://jsfiddle.net/jp4edbxc/1/

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! Extending your example slightly, how would I change the buttons to select a specific chunk of data – so I could have several buttons?
Would it also be possible to update the colour scale with the button (eg to specify different "stops"? 
@m(I added a second dataset to the bottom of the spreadsheet; ultimately I would want to have several datasets, each with its own button. The ranges covered in each dataset means I might need to adjust the colour range for the differences to show up) https://jsfiddle.net/drsimevans/r5LobL8a/

Comment: @morganfree sorry, meant to @ mention you in my reply…

Comment: You have to attach event on each button and add code with series updating, just as in the first button. You can update all axis option with [axis.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/Axis.update), [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r5LobL8a/2/)